# Save matplotlib image throws dimension error

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, save, typeerror

First of all: I am new to all this, please forgive me my ignorance.

I tried to load images from a `TFRecord-File` and I am able to show them with `plt.show()`, but when I try to save the images with `plt.imsave()` I get an error.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

reader = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_file)

for raw_record in reader.take(1):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    raw_record = example.features.feature['image/encoded']
    img = example.features.feature["image/encoded"].bytes_list.value[0]
    decoded = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img)

    plt.figure(figsize = (20,3))
    plt.imshow(decoded)
    plt.show()
    plt.imsave(output_file, decoded)
```

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/freddy/PycharmProjects/ocr/visualize_fsns.py", line 30, in <module>
    plt.imsave(flags.output_file, decoded)
  File "/home/freddy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2235, in        imsave
    return matplotlib.image.imsave(fname, arr, **kwargs)
  File "/home/freddy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1567, in imsave
    rgba = sm.to_rgba(arr, bytes=True)
  File "/home/freddy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 305, in to_rgba
    xx = np.empty(shape=(m, n, 4), dtype=x.dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Could you please help me solve this mystery?

Comment: Can you try `xx = np.empty((m, n, 4))`

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib might be getting confused because [tf.io.decode_jpeg()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_jpeg) returns a Tensor; that could explain the data type error message. Try converting `decoded` to a numpy array with `.numpy()` before plotting.